# How does probability distribution change when changing some events?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I'm preparing for some interviews and I'm stuck on a question which is rather simple, I'm just trying to get my head around how we redefine the sample space.

Given 4 coin flips, you get 1$ for each head you get. What's the expected value of the game (this is trivial = 2), now suppose you can flip an even number of coins after you see your coin flips, what's the expected value of the game now?

I know that if you see 0 heads then you definitely want to flip all 4 again, but how do you decompose the new probability distribution given the results? Also, we also want to flip the 2 T's we see if we have 2H2T, but then again how do we decompose the results?

would appreciate some intuitive response to this.

Edit:

If I have 0 heads, I would flip all 4:

Initially: $P(x=0) = \frac{1}{16}$, after flipping, the expected value is 2, so does this mean that now $P(x=2) = \frac{6}{16} + (\frac{1}{16}\frac{1}{16} + \frac{1}{16}\frac{4}{16})$? I'm kind of stuck as to how knowing the expected value of the second flip changes the initial distribution.

Comment: I don't understand.  Do you mean "you flip four independent fair coins.  After you do this you can, at your option, reflip either $0,2$ or $4$ of them, but not $1$ or $3$. What is the expected number of Heads?"

Comment: @lulu Yes exactly. Another question can be like, you have the option to re-flip all of them or none. It's the idea of re-flipping after you've seen the outcome.

Comment: Ok, so just write it out.  If you see $0$ initially, you reflip all $4$, winding up with an expected $2$.  If you see $1$ initially you flip $2$ again, again winding up with an expected $2$ (Note:  you should confirm that this is optimal in this case, though it is pretty clear.).  And so on.

Comment: Ok, so I get the part about reflipping 4 coins and the expected being 2, however, how does this translate in to the original probability distribution? Also, what if we're flipping 2 out the 4 coins only? Then the expected will be 1. 

So are we mapping expected values of the re-flips to the original probabilities? i.e: p(x=0) -> p(x=2) where x is the number of heads?

Comment: Just go case by case.  I had a $\frac 1{16}$ chance of observing $0$ initially.  With my reflip option, that case now has an expected value of $2$.  Similarly, the case where I see $1$ initially also now has an expected value of $2$.  So...what if I see $2$ initially?  Obviously in that case we flip the other $2$, so what is my expected value in that scenario.  Note:  if I see either $3$ or $4$ initially we should do nothing (that's clear, yes?) so the expected value does not change in those two scenarios.

Comment: My apologies for the somewhat unrelated comment - would you be able to tell me the source of this problem? I am preparing for similar interviews. Thank you.

Comment: @lulu I have edited the original post to show what I am confused about. The part about 3 or 4 is clear, it's just the part of knowing the expectation of the second coin flip and how that changes the first?

Comment: @rubikscube09 this is from glassdoor hedge fund interview

Comment: @skidjoe figured! It's always fun to prepare for these quant interviews (lol).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just go case by case.

Sketch:

We see one of $\{0,1,2,3,4\}$ Heads initially, with easily derived probabilities.

$0$:  probability $\frac 1{16}$.  Then you retoss all $4$, giving you an expected value of $2$.

$1$:  probability $\frac 4{16}$.  Then you retoss two of the Tails, giving you an expected value of $2$ (the one you start with plus $1$ from the two new tosses).  Note:  you could retoss all $4$ if you like, as that also gives you an expected value of $2$.

$2$:  probability $\frac 6{16}$.  Then you retoss the two Tails, giving you an expected value of $3=2+1$  (the $2$ you had initially, plus $1$ from the new two.

$3$:  probability $\frac 4{16}$.  Then you do nothing and keep the $3$.  If you tossed $2$ you;d still have an expected value of $3$ while if you tossed $4$ your expectation would drop to $2$.

$4$:  probability $\frac 1{16}$.  Obviously you do nothing and keep the $4$.

Thus the new expected value is $$\frac 1{16}\times (1\times 2+4\times 2+6\times 3+4\times 3+1\times 4)=\frac 1{16}\times (2+8+18+12+4)=\cdots $$ $$\cdots =\frac {44}{16}=\boxed {2.75}$$

Note:  as a sort of  sanity check, let's suppose you could retoss as many coins as you liked.  Then the only way you get $T$ is if the coin comes up Tails twice in a row (a probability $\frac 14$ event).  Thus, in this case the expected value would be $\frac 34\times 4 = 3$.  Of course it makes sense that the expected value of your game ($2.75$) would be less than this but greater than $2$ (the value you'd get if you had no chance to retoss).